Parametric curve approximation of a space
It is posible to design a parametric curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that, in an intuitive sense, approximates a shape in $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Here, by shape I mean a set or space, or another parametic curve).
For instance, consider the parametric curve
$$
\psi(x, y, z) = \langle r \sin (x) \cos (kx), r \sin(x)  \sin(kx), r \cos(x) \rangle
$$
with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Letting $k \to \infty$ and fixing $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ produces a curve that "converges" to a sphere with radius $r$ centered around $(0, 0, 0)$. By "converges", I mean that there is some natural $N$ such that for any point $p$ of the sphere, $p \in Im(\psi)$ whenever $k > N$.
I have plotted an animation of the curve "building up" the sphere and then "refracting" down into itself with Julia; this is, of the curve with $k \to \infty$ and then with $k \to 0$. The animation can be seen here.
I have no formal understanding of this matter - in fact, I came across the curve $\psi$ by chance when studying the concept of homotopy. Is there a formalization this notion? This is, of the notion of a space which can be approximated with a parametric equation?
PD: Of course, there are spaces which are entirely defined by parametric equations - planes or spheres for instance. But the parametric equations readily determine these spaces, they do not approximate it. I am strictly interested in the notion of approximation or convergence to a space.

Check out Space-filling curves. Even though they are traditionally proven to exist for the solid square $[0,1]^2$, by composing them with a surjective mapping from the square onto the sphere, you can a similar curve onto the sphere. These are not 1-1, The curve goes through many points multiple times.
